# Build gcc plugin using other files

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gcc-plugins

**You probably don't need to know a lot about gcc plugin to understand this problem**

Hi, I am trying to create a gcc plugin that uses other files as `classTree.cpp` and `field.cpp`, I never had a problem building the plugin when I had ne referene to other classes : I was using this command by the way :

```
    g++ -shared -I`g++ -print-file-name=plugin`/include 
           -I`g++ -print-file-name=plugin`/include/c-family -fPIC -fno-rtti -O2  
            order_checker.cpp -o plugin.so
```

and use it with this one :

```
g++  -fplugin=./plugin.so tinytest.cpp -o toto
```

All as showed in the [gcc plugins Doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins-building.html#Plugins-building), they also say that when I am using other files, I just need to add the name of my files like this :

```
    g++ -shared -I`g++ -print-file-name=plugin`/include 
        -I`g++ -print-file-name=plugin`/include/c-family -fPIC -fno-rtti -O2        
         order_checker.cpp classTree.cpp field.cpp -o plugin.so
```

When I use this, `plugin.so` is created, but when I try to run it like before, I get this error :

```
cc1plus: error: cannot load plugin ./plugin.so
./plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZTV5field
```

What does the error mean ? especially the `symbol: _ZTV5field` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_ZTV5field` is<sup>1</sup> the virtual function table for class `field`, as `c++filt` can tell you:

```
$ echo _ZTV5field | c++filt 
vtable for field
```

That this symbol is undefined means that the compiler could not generate this table, which in all likelyhood means that class `field` has a virtual member function that you have forgotten to implement.

<sup>1</sup> in the [Itanium ABI](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) that gcc has been using on non-Windows platforms since version 3.2.